# The bird pointer problem: finding the angle of rotation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry

Suppose we have a bird pointer. He is a guy that likes to point at birds in the sky:

[image: Hand illustration of the problem]

His legs cannot move, however he can rotate around his torso. Also, his body and his arm always make a right angle. Here's a simplified diagram of the problem at hand:

[image]

The problem is, given his torso location $(x_1, y_1)$, body height $h$, and bird location $(x_2, y_2)$, how much should he rotate? The amount of rotation is notated as $t$ in the following diagram (positive is counter clockwise):

[image]

If the angle between his arm and body is 90 degrees, then the angle between his arm and the x axis is the same as the amount of rotation, which is $t$. Therefore we know that $\tan{t} = \frac{y_2-y_3}{x_2-x_3}$.

[image]

We also know that $x_3 = x_1 - h \sin{t}$

and also $y_3 = y_1 + h \cos{t}$

Putting them all together

$\tan{t} = \frac{y_2 - (y_1 + h \cos{t})}{x_2 - (x_1 - h \sin{t})}$

$\frac{\sin{t}}{\cos{t}} = \frac{y_2 - y_1 - h \cos{t}}{x_2 - x_1 + h \sin{t}}$

$(x_2 - x_1 + h \sin{t})\sin{t} = (y_2 - y_1 - h \cos{t})\cos{t}$

Let as denote $x_2 - x_1$ by $dx$ and $y_2 - y_1$ by $dy$. Note that both can be calculated from the problem so those are constants. Then the equation becomes

$(dx + h \sin{t})\sin{t} = (dy - h \cos{t})\cos{t}$

$dx \sin{t} + h \sin^2{t} = dy \cos{t} - h \cos^2{t}$

$h \sin^2{t} + h \cos^2{t} = dy \cos{t} - dx \sin{t}$

$h (\sin^2{t} + \cos^2{t}) = dy \cos{t} - dx \sin{t}$

We then use the trigonometric identity $\sin^2{t} + \cos^2{t} = 1$

$dy \cos{t} - dx \sin{t} = h$

Therefore, I have reduced to problem to an equation of the form

$A \cos{t} + B \sin{t} = C$

However, I have no idea on what to do next to solve for t. Can anyone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Oops, I think after your last diagram you're overthinking things. $t$ doesn't depend on the height of the speaker at all, only the slope of the line between shoulder and target.

From $\tan{t} = \frac{y_2-y_3}{x_2-x_3}$, you could just compute $t=\arctan(\frac{y_2-y_3}{x_2-x_3})$.

---

On a sidenote, $A \cos{t} + B \sin{t} = C$ can be combined using the [linear combination identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_identity#Linear_combinations), but you'd be right back at using $\arctan$, just after a longer walk.

Comment: Thanks. But $y_3$ is $y_1 + h \cos t$ so we would also have $t$ on the right hand side (same with $x_3$ also), which means that it doesn't give us a solution.

Comment: @agro1986 : *The problem is, given his torso location (x1,y1), body height h, and bird location (x2,y2), how much should he rotate? The amount of rotation is notated as t in the following diagram.* I don't really follow. This would seem to retrieve $t$ from the two points, and I don't believe you need the expression you're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the distance from $(x_1,y_1)$ to $(x_2,y_2)$. Call this distance $l$. Now $t=\arccos\left(\dfrac hl\right)$

Comment: Wow, never considered that path. Well, $\arccos (\frac{h}{l})$ is not $t$, but I can now find $t = \arccos (\frac{h}{l}) + \atan2(dy, dx) - \frac{\pi}{2}$